# Sniffing bonjour traffic between iPhone and Mac

Tags: iphone, plist, bonjour, packet-sniffers, tcpdump

My end result is to try and see the plist being sent between my iphone & my mac (I know its a plist because I can see `bplist00` in the hexdump).

I have an app sending data between my iphone to my mac via a bonjour service.

I use tcpdump to capture the traffic and try and transform the payload hexdump into binary to then convert it into a plist text file.

Here are my steps:

1. Make sure the iphone and mac are connected, have the command ready to send
2. Run tcp dump: `sudo tcpdump -vSs 0 -A -i en1 -w Dump.pcap 'tcp port 57097'` on my wireless network (I used [Bonjour Browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/) to find what port the service is registered on), then hit the send command on the phone.
3. Convert the pcap file to a text file: `tshark -V -r Dump.pcap > Dump.txt` (the [end result is this](http://pastebin.com/eqJxs05G))
4. Manually remove the headers and other info from the text file so that I am just left with the payload (we now [have this](http://pastebin.com/8nqx8CGB) in the file)
5. Do a reverse hex dump to convert the file into binary: `xxd -r Dump.txt Dump1.txt`
6. Convert the binary plist to a text file: `plutil -convert xml1 Dump1.txt`

However, at step 6 is where things fail: `Dump1.txt: Property List error: Conversion of string failed. The string is empty. / JSON error: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.` (although it could have been a mistake from an earlier step). And I'm not sure why it reports errors on JSON when I have asked for an XML conversion?

This low level network capturing is not something I am normally akin to (I'm normally higher up with fiddler or charles, but considering this isn't via HTTP I need to go lower down the stack).

Can someone please tell me if what I am doing is correct, or whether there is an easier way to do this?

How can I go about capturing the plist being sent to my mac?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your issue is somewhere around step 4, where you manually edit the request. I was just trying something similar, using Charles rather than tcpdump, and got the exact same error with a payload that I knew contained a plist. Not sure why we got the JSON error message.

I was able to resolve it by directly saving the binary-encoded plist request body from Charles to a file (Charles has a "Save Request" menu option), then run `plutil -convert xml1 FILENAME -o -` on it, and it worked just fine.